# Setting different Y-axis ranges for plot with facets (scales = "free" seems not working)

Tags: r, ggplot2, range, facet, yaxis

I am trying to set different Y-axis ranges for different facets. I read many answers on the web and I tried to apply them on my script, but it seems not working.

I am using `scales = "free"` to make the axis appear on all the facets and I am using `geom_blank` to set different axis limits depending on the variable `Variable` of the `somePoints` dataframe

Here is a reproducible example of the data:

```
library(ggplot2)

dummy <- expand.grid(Year = NA, Season = c("Winter","Spring","Summer","Fall"),
                     Variable = c("P","T"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

dummy$ymin = NA
dummy$ymax = NA
dummy[dummy$Variable=="P","ymin"] = 0
dummy[dummy$Variable=="P","ymax"] = 400
dummy[dummy$Variable=="T","ymin"] = -10
dummy[dummy$Variable=="T","ymax"] = 30

somePoints = expand.grid(Year = NA, Season = c("Winter","Spring","Summer","Fall"),
                         Variable = c("P","T"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

somePoints$Value = NA
somePoints[somePoints$Variable=="P","Year"] = 1940
somePoints[somePoints$Variable=="T","Year"] = 1940
somePoints[somePoints$Variable=="P","Value"] = c(350,365,200,150)
somePoints[somePoints$Variable=="T","Value"] = c(-5,8,25,7)
```

Basically what I want is having the same Y-axis for `P` Variable ranging from 0 to 400 and the same Y-axis for `T` Variable ranging from -10 to 30.

Here are the `ggplot` code lines I am using to obtain what I want:

```
ggplot()+

  facet_grid(Season ~ Variable, scales = "free_y")+

  geom_blank(data = dummy,aes(y=ymin)) +
  geom_blank(data = dummy,aes(y=ymax)) +

  geom_point(data = somePoints, aes(Year,Value), size = 5) +
  geom_point(data = somePoints, aes(Year,Value), size = 5)
```

What I notice is that setting `scales = "free_y"` in the `facet_grid` function seems not working.

What am I doing wrong? I feel I am missing something stupid.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, your issue is more with `geom_blank`.  The purpose of `geom_blank` is to ensure common scales between different plots.  You should use the `expand` argument instead.  I suggest trying the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot()+

  facet_grid(Season ~ Variable, scales = "free_y")+

  geom_point(data = somePoints, aes(Year,Value), size = 5) +
  geom_point(data = somePoints, aes(Year,Value), size = 5) +

  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(.2,0))
```

`expand` is just buffering your edges.

Alternatively, you can use `facet_wrap`, rather than `facet_grid` so that the axes are displayed on each plot.  We'll just specify number of columns (`ncol = 2`) and vertical direction (`vir = "v"`):

```
ggplot()+

  facet_wrap(Variable ~ Season, scales = "free_y",
             dir = "v", ncol = 2)+

  geom_blank(data = dummy,aes(y=ymin)) +
  geom_blank(data = dummy,aes(y=ymax)) +

  geom_point(data = somePoints, aes(Year,Value), size = 5) +
  geom_point(data = somePoints, aes(Year,Value), size = 5) +

  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(.2,0))
```

If you don't like the labels, you can pass `labeller = labeller(.multi_line = FALSE)` to `facet_grid`

Comment: Hi Dave, thank you for replying. I tried to apply your code but in this way I still have the same y axis for both P and T. I want to have the same Y-axis for all the P (going from, say, 0 to 400) and the same Y-axis for all the T (going from -10 to 30). Maybe my question was not clear enough.

Comment: Added a second option for you to your specifications

Comment: Thank you Dave. Using `facet_wrap` solved my problem. It also works fine if I use `facet_grid` inverting `Season` with `Variable`.
Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Yes, that was going to be my other suggestion! `facet_grid` keeps the axes the same within a column and within a row.  In your original case, Season keeps columns (x-axis) the same, and Variable was keeping row axes (y-axis) the same.  Switching them, Season is now keeping row axes (y-axis) the same, and Variable is keeping columns (x-axis) the same.